# Entering $_POST into html form is causing 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php

I have done comment section on my website:

```
<form method="post" name="dodawanieKomentarzy">
<div>Your Name:</div>
<div><input type="text" name="autor" required></div>
<div>Message:</div>
<div><textarea name="komentarz" required></textarea></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Add comment" name="Dodaj"></div>
</form>
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
$pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_dbase_name',
    'my_dbase_login','my_dbase_passw',[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4"]
);
if(isset($_POST['Dodaj'])) {
    $data=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X");
    $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO komentarze VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,'')")->execute([$data,$_POST['autor'],$_POST['komentarz']]);
};
?>
```

Everything works (I can insert normal text (for example :'This is comment'), but when I insert for example: '$_POST' to text field, I've got 403 Forbidden error.
I don't see what is wrong with the code, so I would appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: I also can't insert string "$_POST" in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: How do you know this problem is related to PDO?

Comment: Good question. I have tried with mysqli before and it doesn't work too. PhpMyAdmin can't insert record with $_POST text too.

Comment: Good question is whether you see this error without any database related code at all

Comment: Code work well if I fill form with "normal" characters.

Comment: Did I say a word "character"?

Comment: If I delete table `komentarze` I've got 403 forbidden too.

Comment: can you delete ALL database related code? starting from $pdo=new PDO?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";
if(isset($_POST['Dodaj'])) {
  try {
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $data=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X");
    $author = $_POST['autor'];
    $komentarz = $_POST['komentarz'];
    $insert_query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO komentarze (`autor`,`komentarz`) VALUES ('".$author."', '".$komentarz."' )");
    $insert_query->execute();
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $insert_query . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}    
?>
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in /home/zsem2/DEV.php on line 14
New record created successfully

Comment: oops sorry you have to use this one to execute your comment   $insert_query->execute();

Answer (score -1):

You can try with variable like: `$author= $_POST['autor']; $text = $_POST['komentarz'];` then use $author and $text both to your query.

Comment: Also u missing column in your query "INSERT INTO komentarze (author, komentarze) VALUES (':author, :komentarze')"

Comment: No, because I can send to MySQL other text, but only not $_POST.